# How to check the Install Unknown Apps Toggle is on / off dynamically in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions, settings, android-togglebutton

I have added the below code for redirecting to the Install Unknown Apps Screen run time using Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES.

But how do I check the Toggle button is On or Off?

I need to download the APK file if Install Unknown Resouces enabled otherwise it needs to be redirected to the Permissions page that indicated in the image.

[Click this image to check for more..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ifkW.jpg)

```
    package com.example.demoapp;
    
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.Settings;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        Button mButtonDownload;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            mButtonDownload = findViewById(R.id.btn_click);
    
            mButtonDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    boolean appInstalled = isAppInstalled("com.example.demoapp");
                    if (appInstalled) {
                        System.out.println("App already installed.");
    
                        Intent intent = null;
                        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                            intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES);
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    
        private boolean isAppInstalled(String packageName) {
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            boolean installed = false;
            try {
                pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
                installed = true;
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                installed = false;
            }
            return installed;
        }
    }
```

Please suggest me in advance.

Comment: why you need to check the status of the button when you have already redirected to specific settings screen? I don't think so you can have check on the toggle state through some API otherwise you need to find `android:id` for it then check status, but it may not be good way as in future or custom ROM it might get changed.

Comment: Actually, I need the APK to download if the toggle button is On. So the purpose of the find the status of the Toggle button if it is disabled or enabled.

Comment: Again, if you want to download apk through your app it should be done through user consent, not based on this toggle check, you won't find any app doing so as it is main reason to provide such a security settings. Still you want to check then as I mentioned in earlier comment you are opening settings activity on which you need to find toggle button's id to retrieve its instant to check if its enabled or not. There are two issues 1] you won't have much control on UI post settings activity launch. 2] Even if you do, it has to be automated which again makes your app suspicious of malware/virus.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66729034

Comment: Is `packageManager.canRequestPackageInstalls()` what you're looking for?